# How to upload the python packages to Nexus sonartype private repo

Tags: python, nexus, pypi

I have configured the Nexus-OSS-3.14 private Python artifact server on aws cloud. I want to be maintain all my project related Python packages on my private repository server.

I downloaded the all the Python packages on my local Linux box and I want to be upload all the Python packages to private Python artifact server.

I have tried curl put request and I didn't upload and your help is needed to complete this.

I have tried curl put request:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin --upload-file boto3-1.9.76-py2.py3-none-any.whl https://artifact.example.com/repository/ASAP-Python-2.7-Hosted/
```

When I used that command and I get 404 response.

Comment: You could check out [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/). Worked fine for me with a Nexus on a corporate network

Comment: You can't use a simple PUT, PyPi repositories don't work that way. Use twine as suggested above or use the [REST API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api#ComponentsAPI-UploadComponent).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the recommended approach is to use `twine`, something like this should work:

```
pip install twine
twine upload --repository https://artifact.example.com/repository/ASAP-Python-2.7-Hosted/ boto3-1.9.76-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

It should ask for your username and password. To make life a bit easier you can create `$HOME/.pypirc` file with the URL, username and password

```
[nexus]
repository: https://artifact.example.com/repository/ASAP-Python-2.7-Hosted/
username: admin
password: admin
```

Then when you call `twine`, do so like this:

```
twine upload --repository nexus boto3-1.9.76-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

It's not a hard requirement, but if you're on multi user system and you've put a password in the file you should probably do

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.pypirc
```

Comment: When i used the repository credentials on the pip.conf and credentials are not used by python when we download/upload packages from repository.
How do we hard code credentials for PyPi repository ? what is the best way to have credentials ?

Comment: You need to create a `$HOME/.pypirc` file. I'll add it to the answer so it's formatted correctly.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks for your valuable answer.
When I download the packages its asking the password to authenticate the repo.
I tried the above configuration which you mentioned on this thread.
Its not working.

Comment: Weird. I assume you mean upload? 
You could try pointing directly at the file with `twine upload --config-file <FILEPATH>` you could also try setting the user/pass as args `twine upload -u <USER> -p <PASS>`. It's probably worth adding `--verbose` too, so you can see what's happening. Other than that, I'm really not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: **.pypirc** file format is out-dated. Please refer https://packaging.python.org/specifications/pypirc/

Comment: It looks ok to me, was there something specific that's wrong?

Comment: In my cases it got working:  

1) uploading without .pypirc by `--repository-url -u -p --non-interactive`; 
2) uploading with .pypirc by `--config-file path/.pypirc --non-interactive`; 
3) uploading with .pypirc by `~/.pypirc` (with no additional keys); 

All of them are not asking for any creds or confirms, 
but exactly [pypi] section should be specified within when using .pypirc

Comment: If you upload using url directly (without .pypirc), use `--repository-url` instead of `--repository`.

Answer (score 9):

Pip (yarn) for download. Twine for upload. 
Configuration:

*be careful with trailing slashes!*

### Download with pip (yarn)

`pip config edit [--editor [nano|code|...]] [--global|--user]` for edit config

```
[global]
index = https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi/pypi
index-url = https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi/simple
```

Or set environment variables. Dockerfile for example:

```
ENV \
  PIP_INDEX=https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi/pypi \
  PIP_INDEX_URL=https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi/simple
```

Or use command line args `pip install --index`

### Upload with twine

Edit `.pypirc`:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
pypi
[pypi]
repository: https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi-hosted/
username: nexususername
password: nexuspassword
```

Or environment

```
ENV \
  TWINE_REPOSITORY_URL=https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi-hosted/ \
  TWINE_USERNAME=nexususername \
  TWINE_PASSWORD=nexuspassword
```

Or command line

`twine upload --repository-url`

Answer (score 1):

At first install twine:

```
pip install twine
```

then create  `.pypirc` in `$HOME/.pypirc` with this content

```
[distutils]
index-servers = nexus
[nexus]
repository = http://SERVER_IP:SERVER_PORT/repository/pypi-hosted/
username = username
password = password
```

And upload python packages with

```
twine upload --repository nexus nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```