# Modify requiremet.txt file to install from private repos on heroku

Tags: python, git, github, heroku

I have an app deployed in Heroku , now I got a lot of private repos need to be included in requirements.txt file , I set my GitHub access token and need to put it in Heroku environment variables to be included in requirements.txt file , I already tried a lot to pass it but its not read by the file unless I hard code it inside it , what should be done to make this step as secure as possible?

Comment: Are your private repository estrictly Python libraries? Are you using some private artifactory like Nexus?

Comment: they are python projects with setup.py

Comment: How are you test them in your localhost? Is for an enterprise or just a poc?

Comment: for an organization , i test it locally by simply hard coding but this is not secure

Answer (score 0):

### Choose a private repository

For an organization and private libraries, you have only one option, no matter the language:

An artifact repository.

- You need to deploy it and configure it
- Push your private libraries.
- Create a user/password and configure them in the machine where yo build your apps. Also you could create another user for your developers. There are roles like write, read only, etc

I advice you:

[image]

- [How to upload the python packages to Nexus sonartype private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592918/how-to-upload-the-python-packages-to-nexus-sonartype-private-repo)
- https://www.zepl.com/use-your-private-python-libraries-from-artifactory-in-zepl/

### Download the private packages

No matter the cloud (aws, gcp, heroku, etc), you only need to configure the credentials and url of your private repository using the shell or a config file.

Here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657209/3957754):

```
.pypirc:

[distutils]
index-servers =
pypi
[pypi]
repository: https://nexus.your.domain/repository/pypi-hosted/
username: nexususername
password: nexuspassword
```

If you are worried about the credentials, you could do a simple automation to read them from env variable or perform a replacement

```
password: ${PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD}
```

```
password: <PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD>
```

This generic approach (any private repository & any cloud) should work with github:

- https://truveris.github.io/articles/configuring-pypirc/
- https://gist.github.com/NearHuscarl/90aa951dc970e8a6bd0ceba3d6846c14

Comment: github artifactory?